# Using exclusively Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout-3.0

I have the following situation, I have many scripts and they conflict with each other.

I want to use something like that:

```
$Bootstrap3('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

And for jQuery(normally `$`).

**UPDATED**

My task is to add Bootstrap to an existing project([css problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937566/inheritance-overwriting-existing-css-rules-from-different-external-files)), I have `bootstrap`, `Knockout`, `JQuery` and someother scripts.

I wanted to access the `bootstrap`-code explicit, so that I can make sure that no other scripts will be affected(because I don't know that project and I don't know how they will react with bootstrap.js)

My current script order(I get no errors at the moment, but the project is big, so I don't know what will happen):

```
var bootstrap3 = new Bundle("~/Scripts/bundle/CoreScripts").Include(
// "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.js",//used before, commented out
"~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",// what I added
"~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",// what I added
"~/Scripts/jquery.formatter/jquery.formatter-0.1.5.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui-1.11.3.js",
"~/Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js",
"~/Scripts/knockout/knockout.mapping-2.4.1.js",
"~/Scripts/formvalidator.net/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.js",
"~/Scripts/iban/iban.js",
"~/Scripts/sweetalert/sweet-alert.js",
"~/Scripts/jsNumberFormatter/jsnumberformatter.js",
"~/Scripts/jsNumberFormatter/jsnumberformatter.locale.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-de.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.js");
bootstrap3.Orderer = new BundleOrderer();
bundles.Add(bootstrap3);
```

Only the core libs are shown above.

Something like this `$Bootstrap3(...)` would be cool... and I don't want to use for all the other scripts something like `.noConlfict()`

Comment: In which way they conflict? I used to see pages with 20-30 scripts, without any conflict, so maybe you should fix some code.

Comment: mhhh, what could be done ...

Comment: Why don't you just learn how to use CSS and JavaScript and do it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap plugins all have a method called [noConflict](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#js-noconflict) that does what you're looking for.

```
// return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict()
// give $().bootstrapBtn the Bootstrap functionality
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton
```

After this code runs  `$('#example').button()` will be what it was before bootstrap was loaded and `$('#example').bootstrapBtn()` will be plugin from bootstrap.

For this to work, the bootstrap JS file will have to be loaded after the one with a name conflict.