# inheritance/overwriting existing CSS rules from different external files

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I got an existing project, which used to be without Bootstrap(3), but now I have to change that and keep the old css stuff.

My current CSS order:

```
var bundleCSS = new StyleBundle("~/Views/bundle/newBundle").Include(
                    "~/Views/Shared/normalize.css",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-latest.custom.css",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css",
                    "~/Scripts/sweetalert/sweet-alert.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Views/Shared/OldButNeededLayout.css",
                    "~/Content/custom.css"); //will be rendered in that order
```

The `custom.css` is used to fix all errors that come from adding `bootstrap.css` to the project.

The problem here is, that `OldButNeededLayout.css` has roundabout 3000 lines of css-code and by the way the current project is quite big.

So when overwriting bootstrap with that old css and than fixing the errors, which came by adding bootstrap, than I get an unpredictable results.(because I dont't know where it will change something)

What to do or how to solve integrating bootstrap css/js into (my) existing project(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a messy way to integrate Bootstrap whilst trying to avoid making any changes to the `OldButNeededLayout` file...

In my experience, integrating Bootstrap into an existing project is quite an undertaking and requires extensive modification of your HTML (adding classes and modifying markup structures) as well as extensive modification of your existing CSS, in order to make it play nice with Bootstrap.

Your approach will make maintenance difficult and will also deliver a lot of unnecessary CSS code to the client.

I would suggest:

1. Remove the `OldButNeededLayout` css from your project and clear the
   contents of `custom` so that the vast majority of css is from
   Bootstrap.
2. Obviously, this will look nothing like your site should, so
3. Methodically fix each bit of layout or styling that needs to change,
   in your `custom` css until you have a site which resembles your
   pre-Bootstrap site. Use bits from `OldButNeededLayout` that are
   necessary, but make sure each and every style property is necessary.

This is a lot of work, of course, but it will result in a project which is more maintainable, predictable and concise for the client.

I don't see it as a reasonable expectation that you can just throw Bootstrap onto a large project and not expect to make major changes to your existing HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestion isn't ideal and there's certainly better ways of implementing what you need, but I've kept my suggestion in line with your requirement...

In your new custom.css file, you could try being more specific when declaring an element. So if in OldButNeededLayout.css you overrode Bootstrap's style such as:

```
.divclass .jumbotron h1 {
   color: red;
}
```

You could be declare a higher level of specificity in your custom.css file to ensure it will override what you in OldButNeededLayout.css:

```
.parent .divclass .jumbotron h1 {
   color: blue;
}
```